# Eliminate boilerplate parameters using Ninject in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository, ninject

A lot of our repositories are plagued with boilerplate parameters concerning date range, as our application is very date-range sensitive as such:

```
public static IEnumerable<Records> GetByClient(int clientId, DateTime start, DateTime end){}
public static IEnumerable<Records> GetByRegion(int regionId, DateTime start, DateTime end){}
```

Is there a good way to resolve this by passing DateTime start and DateTime end from http request level all the way down to repository level using Ninject in .NET MVC ?

These repositories would have the "Request" scope, hence disposed after each request, and since each request only has one time range, Ninject would create repositories with appropriate start / end time as repository level properties? and repo methods would look somewhat like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Records> GetByClient(int clientId){
  query.Where(c=>c.Date >= startDate && c.Date <= endDate)...

}
```

I'm sure this has been done many times before, any tip would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Steven's answer, there's two ways how you can get the data on the ninject context.

a) Putting the `IDateRangeContext` on the ninject context as `IParameter` p.Ex by using a factory: use `IResolutionRoot.Get<Foo>(new ConstructorArgument("dateRangeContext", dateRangeContext, true)` --> true is for inheriting.
This way any object instanciated by the foo request, including dependencies, can have the `IDateRangeContext` constructor injected as parameter named "dateRangeContext" (you could also roll your own `IParameter` which maches the type / `IDateRangeInterface` but doesn't care what the argument name is).

b) `Bind<IDateRangeContext().To<DateRangeContext>().InRequestScope()`, then have it injected @ http level and set Start & End properties there. For better separation, you can also have the context implement two interfaces:

```
public interface IDateRangeContext {
    DateTime Start { get; }
    DateTime End { get;
}

public interface IDateRangeContextWithSetter : IDateRangeContext {
    DateTime Start { get; set; }
    DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

and then bind both to the same instance in RequestScope:

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<IDateRangeContext, IDateRangeContextWithSetter>().To<DateRangeContext>().InRequestScope();
```

The context preservation extension might also be useful, in case you are late-creating (through "factory") objects which need to be in the same context as well: 
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.contextpreservation/wiki
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation/2.2.0.5

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your application is missing an abstraction. Since your application "is very date-range sensitive" as you put it, and this information seems more 'contextual' than it is runtime date, that date range deserves its own abstraction. For instance:

```
public interface IDateRangeContext
{
    DateTime Start { get; }
    DateTime End { get; }
}
```

This way you can easily inject such `IDateRangeContext` into other services that need it. This also makes it very clear which services are related to date ranges.

The same way might the `clientId` and `regionId` be fixed for a given request. In other words, they will probably be contextual values as well. Promote them to a service as well:

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    int ClientId { get; }
    int Regionid { get; }
}
```

Comment: Totally follow. Any tips on how to communicate date range from http level to back end? kernel.Bind<IDateRangeContext>().ToMethod(???).InRequestScope(); What should the method look like? Thanks

Comment: @BZapper, can you update your question an give an example where this date info is coming from?